# getting the error "Medium without key" while installing my rpm from my repo

Tags: linux, gnupg, rpm

**O.S: Mageia** *5*

**Problem:**

1. I build rpm , sign it and add it to my private repo.
2. I exported my key using the command  gpg --export -a 'MY NAME' > RPM-GPG-KEY-pmanager
3. I took this key and imported it to the PC where I want to install the rpm using rpm --import
4. I have the error

   /var/cache/urpmi/rpms/my_rpm_name.rpm: Medium without key (OK (RSA/SHA1, Mon 16 Sep 2019 03:50:12 PM EEST, Key ID 351f1c3a**b40c2563**))
5. I can see the key

   rpm -qa | grep ^gpg-pubkey-

   gpg-pubkey-**b40c2563**-58ecf275

   rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release} --> %{summary}\n'
   gpg-pubkey-**b40c2563-58ecf275** --> gpg(NAME & email here)

What I am missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media directory needs to contain the pub key as well. 
This solved the issue.